# This but not $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

OK so in jQuery;

I have a selecter `$("#gmap")`

I want to do alot of code in context of my selector.  I have always been lazy and used .each() even though there is only one of them.

```
$("#gmap321654987789").each(function(){
 $(this).....
});
```

Is this particuarly effitiant? I hate code that doesn't feel 'right'.

Is there a mechanism for say... or something similar.

```
$("#gmap321654987789").this(function(){
 $(this).....
});
```

Comment: What became of the good old `=` operator?

Comment: I don't think that's inefficient at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cache the object and work with it like normal:

```
var $gmap = $('#gmap321654987789'); // Get your jQuery object
console.log($gmap);
console.log($gmap.text());
```

Comment: Cheers, went with this method, well sort of. Its for a CMS so have to handle multiple maps with unique Identifyers... wrote a function in a standalone JS file, then in the XSL I can iterate through;
for-each map
doStufftoMap($('#gmap321654987789'));

Answer (score 2):

well if there is only one one them (should be because you are selecting by id) you can just chain methods `$("#gmap").val("new").attr('someattr','')`.etc

Answer (score 1):

You could just:

```
var myElement = $("#gmap321654987789");
myElement....
```

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to be able to do this in a chain

Comment: And what hinders him? `myelement.css('foo', 'bar').hide().show()...`

Comment: @Gipsy King: Good point, I assumed there was something more he wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "with" in JS so you focus on the properties of your object.

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.me = function(func) {
        func.call(this[0]);
        return this;    
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and use with:

```
$("#gmap321654987789").me(function(){
    this.innerHTML = 'edited';
}).css('border')....
```

Comment: although I don't think using each is so bad

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a function pattern? Perhaps you could cut your implementation down to one or more methods, or even just a single parametrised method.

```
$.fn.doThingsToAMap = function() {
    $(this).doThis();
    $(this).doThat();
    return this;
};


$("#gmap321654987789").doThingsToAMap();
```