# How do I perform a function on a single jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often make use of the `each` method in jQuery, such as the following:

```
 $('#thing img').each(function(){
     //do some stuff
 });
```

...where the function is performed on each element in the jQuery object.
Is there a method/syntax for performing an action on the only (or first matched) element in the object?

I'm imagining something like

```
 $('#thing img').do(function(){
     //do some stuff
 });
```

*I don't need to use jQuery but can, as the application in question already makes use of it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't complicate the matter:

```
var thisImg = $('#thing img')[0];
//do some stuff with thisImg
```

Comment: You may want to mention the object returned is no longer a jQuery object.

Comment: The `this` inside the `each` function is not a jQuery object as well, so hopefully OP won't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector.

Try:

```
$('#thing img').eq(0).each(function(){
     //do some stuff
 });
```

or

```
$('#thing img:eq(0)').each(function(){
     //do some stuff
 });
```

or(based on @John's inputs)

```
   $('#thing img').first().each(function(){
         //do some stuff
     });
```

Comment: There's also the equivalent `.first()`, which may be more obvious at a glance.

Comment: I see what you mean. In posting the question it became apparent to me that jQuery methods __must__, by nature, be designed to handle objects with multiple component elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just limit the selector to the first element like so:

```
$('#thing img:eq(0)').each(function(){
 //do some stuff on the first response only
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you use `return false` statement to break the loop once your stuff is done

```
 $('#thing img').each(function(){
     //do some stuff for 1st matched item then

return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [This but not $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747716/this-but-not-this/4747782#4747782)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.me = function(func) {
        func.call(this[0]);
        return this;    
    }
})(jQuery);
```